# Changing value of variable in config file while running Docker

Tags: java, docker

I have a variable `Mode` in a configuration file that I am using in my Java code. I use this variable in method `validateInput`. This method checks the sequence of some input messages and based on the value of the `Mode` variable it either accepts these values (in case `Mode` is flexible) or throws an exception (in case `Mode` is strict). The default of `Mode` is strict.

Now I'm using docker to run my code and so the `Mode` is strict. But then while running tests multiple times, `validateInput` throws an exception because it is not in sequence anymore. I know I can manually set the `Mode` to flexible when testing before I start my Docker but what I would like is to be able to change the `Mode` value while running my Docker. I would prefer to not restart my Docker for this because this takes a while. Is this somehow possible? Or if not, are there alternatives to setting it manually?

Comment: Hi, you should consider some options here: store/take your configuration in/from database; or reload your configurations with (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html)

Comment: How are you loading your configuration in the code?  How does the configuration get into the container?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Microprofile config provider to get the values from the configuration file into the java code.